# Change PK Clustered to non-clustered on table that is in use

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

We have an AspState db which created the AspNetUsers by default with a PK on Id (which is of the type nvarchar(128) and is clustered. Perfomance of this table is terrible due to lack of knowledge in the past. We want to try to speed up the table by adding an identity_col, and moving the Clustered index from the Id (which represents a guid now) to the identity_col.
While reading on various famous resources and answers already given there are comments regarding "You can't do this if this table has already been used / has indexes referring to the PK". I do not understand this claim (lack of knowledge) and want to ask what the proper way of doing this would be.

Current steps and SQL statements are.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.AspNetUsers DROP CONSTRAINT PK_dbo.AspNetUsers
Go
ALTER TABLE dbo.AspNetUsers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_dbo.AspNetUsers
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id)
Go

#Add new identitycolumn
ALTER TABLE AspNetUsers ADD identity_col INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

From here I would need to add a Clustered-index to the identity-column, but what do I have to do with all the dependencies on the PK (which is now non-clustered), because I assume we do not want to change the Pk from the Id to the identity_col ?

Comment: The *"You can't do this if this table has already been used / has indexes referring to the PK"* statement is saying that if you have a primary key, and one (or more) other tables/columns are using that primary key as a foreign key then you *can't* `DROP` that primary key. You would have to `DROP` all the related foreign key constraints first before you can `DROP` the primary key.

Comment: That is somewhat logical.

Comment: If the PK stays the PK, you don't need to do anything with dependencies such as foreign keys.  If all you are doing is changing the column that is clustered, you are just changing the order that the data is stored on disk.

Comment: That is true, but as @Larnu stated, I can't drop it if it has references to it. Right now I found a script that makes "drop" and "create" constraint statements, so I can drop them and creat them after wards